Color Management Folder Location?
Trying to find the 4.2\datafiles\colormanagement folder but it is nowhere on my system. I downloaded 4.2 from Steam, so is that interfering?
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.2 only has three folders: \config, \extensions, and \scripts
Just trying to get control over color mgmt from Cycles -> AE...

I think that you want to look under C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.2\4.2\datafiles\colormanagement

Sadly I do not have C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation. I'm thinking it's maybe because I downloaded Blender through Steam?

Answered my own question. Blender downloads to the steam apps folder this way.
